# Contract invoke error: 'Contract pre-release number does not match host' on Stellar using Soroban

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, error, smart-contract

I have deployed the crowdfunding contract on **Stellar's Futurenet**. When I invoke the contract functions on the terminal using the **soroban cli**, it gives the error `contract pre-release number does not match host`

Invoke Command:

```
soroban contract invoke \
--id CA2JCQPFHIVOUZKZ4KFGYFQ3W4K7SOGBXHK4F3PNZIKBVRIRSUR7IYPN \
--source _HERE_MY_PRIVATE_KEY_ \
--rpc-url https://rpc-futurenet.stellar.org:443 \
--network-passphrase 'Test SDF Future Network ; October 2022' \
-- \
initialize \
--dev_acc GBGHJTGWJL7NYQSKLC2KLVM2ZTSOANW2K2JKRD3PDG6IER7DMK5JATJC \
--launchpad_acc GAEODB2BANWODOTBYAMQ4UYQFTZDINZI35TCGI4Y23W7VQ3A7ZLNKFRE \
--arty_token GCUM3RPLXCRZACLTN4554JBGCEJZ6SI6T3MLU6Q6WNLTQVGBIHYPFMXN \
--token_admin GCZLDZKHME36TKUXBC76WPEXUL4WQP5TH6URJ2TPJFZYMWJPRVZYWHYJ
```

Error:

```
error: transaction simulation failed: HostError: Error(WasmVm, InvalidInput)
Event log (newest first):
 0: [Diagnostic Event] topics:[error, Error(WasmVm, InvalidInput)], data:"contract 
 pre-release number does not match host"
 1: [Diagnostic Event] topics:[fn_call, 
 Bytes(349141e53a2aea6559e28a6c161bb715f938c1b9d5c2ededca141ac5119523f4), 
  initialize], data:[Address(Account(4c74ccd64afedc424a58b4a5d59acce4e036da5692a88f6f19bc8247e362ba90)),Address(Account(08e18741036ce1ba61c0190e53102cf2343728df66232398d6edfac360fe56d5)),Address(Account(a8cdc5ebb8a39009736f3bde242611139f491e9ed8ba7a1eb3573854c141f0f2)),Address(Account(b2b1e5476137e9aa9708bfeb3c97a2f9683fb33fa914ea6f497386592f8d738b))]
```